# Apollo query subscription doesn't have extensions part in Error

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo

subscription callback only provides a basic error message and lacks additional details such as error code and type, while the network tab displays a properly structured errors array, it suggests that the subscription isn't transmitting the complete error object

I tried several changes

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Add errorPolicy: 'all' in your query it will resolve your issue and will provide proper error like this:
[result][1]
```

```html
    this.apollo.watchQuery({
      query: GET_DATA,
      **errorPolicy: 'all',** // Set the desired error policy here
    })
   .subscribe({ //and handle this subscription part according to your version
      next: (result) => {
        // Handle successful response
      },
      error: (error) => {
        // Handle error
      }
    });
```

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTqZ0.png
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).